# INDIRECT from another sheet

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to figure out the correct syntax to have this formula reference a different sheet.
I need `=INDIRECT((ADDRESS(((COUNTA($E$5:$E$204))/2)+4,7)))` to reference sheet `Line 3`

Comment: Look This:-https://exceljet.net/formula/dynamic-named-range-with-index

Comment: Are you looking for this? `=INDIRECT((ADDRESS(((COUNTA('Line 3'!$E$5:$E$204))/2)+4,7)))`

Comment: Justnya MK - I tried that and while COUNTA finds the middle cell of the range on "Line 3" ADDESS is still pulling the cell value from the active sheet.
I also tied adding the sheet text to the end of the ADDRESS function but it returns a #VALUE! error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the range `$E$5:$E$204` refers to the same sheet as the one containing the formula, then you could use the `Sheet_text` argument of the Address function:

```
=INDIRECT((ADDRESS(((COUNTA($E$5:$E$204))/2)+4,7,,,"Line 3")))
```

If you also want the referenced cell range to be from the `Line 3` worksheet, then:

```
=INDIRECT((ADDRESS(((COUNTA('Line 3'!E5:E204))/2)+4,7,,,"Line 3")))
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Ron Rosenfeld & Justnya MK, I'm an idiot my syntax for the `Sheet_Text` was missing the extra 2 `,`